# Does WSGI behave dynamicly?

Tags: php, python, django, mod-wsgi

I remember when I save my files in PHP language, it didn't need to restart or reload apache web server.

In Python, specialy Django, If I use django webserver with `runserver` command,it needs to restart django if I change my files. Question is, if I use WSGI in server, Does it behave such as php or `runserver` command?

Comment: Why would you be editing files on a live server?

Comment: Because I need to change a variable or some html. @DanielRoseman

Comment: You would do that by making the change in development, committing to version control, then re-deploying which would restart the WSGI process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify static files or html template, you should be fine without reloading your server.

 But you will need to `reload` your apache server if you change any of your python files.